1990s action movie about a Vietnam veteran turned watchmaker and a psychologist lady
A New York watchmaker and Vietnam vet saves child and mother from a blazing house. Being a public focus attracts attention of former war conspiracists who try to kill him. Being on the run, he persuades a customer of his, a lady psychologist, to associate with him, fall in love and bring matters to a happy end.

Sounds like Timebomb (1991).
WikiPedia synopsis:

Mild-mannered watchmaker Eddy Kay (Michael Biehn) runs into a burning building to save a trapped woman and is featured in the news as a result. Watching the news, Colonel Taylor (Richard Jordan) is shocked to see Eddy, whom he had assumed to be dead. A game of cat and mouse begins as Eddy, with the help of psychiatrist Dr. Anna Nolmar (Patsy Kensit), tries to discover his past and why they want him dead.



You are right. Thank you very much. The movie, I think, is good fun to watch.
